# Collection of a type that does not have equals and hashCode

Tags: java, equals

I have to use a type from a 3rd party library that does not have `equals` and `hashCode`.

In my example this will be played by the class `Box` which contains some data.
I have create a custom static method which compares to instances according to the specification. In the example if the data are the same.

The problem is that my implementation still does not take into account the cardinality of the unique instances.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.function.BiPredicate;

import static org.assertj.core.util.Lists.newArrayList;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

class CustomEqualsTest {

    public static final BiPredicate<Box, Box> EQUALS = CustomEqualsTest::equals;

    static boolean equals(Box b1, Box b2) {
        if (b1 == b2) {
            return true;
        }
        if (b1 != null && b2 != null) {
            return Objects.equals(b1.data, b2.data);
        }
        return false;
    }

    static class Box {
        Integer data;

        private Box(Integer data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        static Box of(Integer data) {
            return new Box(data);
        }
        // intentionally skip equals
        // intentionally skip hashCode
    }

    @Test
    void testCustomEquals() {
        assertTrue(equals(
                newArrayList(Box.of(1)),
                newArrayList(Box.of(1)), EQUALS));
        assertFalse(equals(
                newArrayList(Box.of(1)),
                newArrayList(), EQUALS));
        assertFalse(equals(
                newArrayList(Box.of(1)),
                newArrayList((Box) null), EQUALS));
        assertFalse(equals(
                newArrayList(Box.of(1)),
                newArrayList(Box.of(2)), EQUALS));
        assertFalse(equals(
                newArrayList(Box.of(1), Box.of(1)),
                newArrayList(Box.of(1)), EQUALS));

        // This fails:
        assertFalse(
                equals(
                        newArrayList(Box.of(1), Box.of(1), Box.of(2)),
                        newArrayList(Box.of(1), Box.of(2), Box.of(2)),
                        EQUALS));

    }

    static <T> boolean equals(Collection<T> collection1, Collection<T> collection2, BiPredicate<T, T> equals) {
        if (collection1.size() != collection2.size()) {
            return false;
        }

        for (T t1 : collection1) {
            boolean match = false;
            for (T t2 : collection2) {
                if (equals.test(t1, t2)) {
                    match = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!match) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with that collection equals method? You compare every element from 1st collection to every element from 2nd collection, which is strange. Shouldn't you compare 1sl element to 1st element, then 2nd to 2nd and so on? Also is there any specific reason you don't extend the class the provide equals and hashCode implementations to suit your needs?

Comment: My first idea was to map the instances to their cardinality.  How should I count instances that I cannot put in a HashMap, or can I?

Comment: @Chaosfire to answer your last question this calss is an `Entity` which is generated from UML. On the other according to our new spec. two instances are equals if some of their fields are equal but not all of them (and this ignores the id).

To the other questions.: there is not quarantee on the order of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't provide `equals` and `hashCode`, most collections are out of the question. This leaves us only with tree structures([TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) to be precise) and custom [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to work with. Example null safe comparator:

```
public static final Comparator<Box> COMPARATOR = Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(Box::getData));
```

Count the elements in each collection using `TreeMap`

```
static <T> boolean equals(Collection<T> collection1, Collection<T> collection2, BiPredicate<T, T> equals, Comparator<T> comparator) {
  if (collection1.size() != collection2.size()) {
    return false;
  }
  
  Map<T, Integer> m1 = new TreeMap<>(comparator);
  for (T t : collection1) {
    m1.merge(t, 1, Integer::sum);
  }
  Map<T, Integer> m2 = new TreeMap<>(comparator);
  for (T t : collection2) {
    m2.merge(t, 1, Integer::sum);
  }
  
  if (m1.size() != m2.size()) {
    return false;
  }
  Iterator<Map.Entry<T, Integer>> m2Iterator = m2.entrySet().iterator();
  for (Map.Entry<T, Integer> m1Entry : m1.entrySet()) {
    Map.Entry<T, Integer> m2Entry = m2Iterator.next();
    if (!equals.test(m1Entry.getKey(), m2Entry.getKey())) {
      return false;
    }
    if (!m1Entry.getValue().equals(m2Entry.getValue())) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Entries now will be in the same order, so we can safely compare current keys(Box) with current counts.

Other option would be to collect collections to sorted lists and compare each element.

```
static <T> boolean equals(Collection<T> collection1, Collection<T> collection2, BiPredicate<T, T> equals, Comparator<T> comparator) {
  if (collection1.size() != collection2.size()) {
    return false;
  }
  
  List<T> l1 = collection1.stream().sorted(comparator).collect(Collectors.toList());
  List<T> l2 = collection2.stream().sorted(comparator).collect(Collectors.toList());
  for (int i = 0; i < l1.size(); i++) {
    if (!equals.test(l1.get(i), l2.get(i))) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

If collections are guaranteed to be lists and you don't need to keep them in input order, it's possible to sort directly without streaming. I would stick with 2nd option, if possible, it's shorter and more readable i think.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I like this solution. 
I was thinking about injecting a T -> hashCode mapping into a `Map` and forgot about TreeMap.